# Tessnet2 for .Net - exits at the tessocr.Init call

Tags: .net, tesseract

I have a .net console app running in Visual Studio 10, Windows Vista Home Premium.  I am trying to get the tessnet2 example to work.  here is my code:

```
        Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\aaa\a-nsl\Caselines\Scanned Documents\Test_Scan_04.jpg"))
        {
            var tessocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            tessocr.Init(@"C:\Users\Paul\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\tessnet2Wpf\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug", "eng", false);
            tessocr.GetThresholdedImage(bmp, Rectangle.Empty).Save("c:\\temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".bmp");
            // Tessdata directory must be in the directory than this exe
            Console.WriteLine("Multithread version");
            ocr.DoOCRMultiThred(bmp, "eng");
            Console.WriteLine("Normal version");
            ocr.DoOCRNormal(bmp, "eng");
        }
```

The application exits with code 1 at the tessocr.Init call.

I have placed all 9 eng language files in the debug directory of the application.

Not sure what else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

They need to be in a directory called "tessdata".